# Denying access for specific host to specific database on mysql

Tags: mysql, permissions, remote-access

We have a production MySQL server with the following grants:

```
mysql> show grants for the_db;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for db_user@%                                                                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'db_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*A236932DB5549260BDC088C4BC2F0C6DB04424D7' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `xydb`.* TO 'db_user'@'%'                                                      |
| GRANT SELECT ON `xyie-db`.* TO 'db_user'@'%'                                                           |
| GRANT SELECT ON `supportdb`.* TO 'db_user'@'%'                                                         |
| GRANT SELECT ON `xbs`.* TO 'db_user'@'%'                                                               |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is it possible to block access to these databases for a specific host? We have a new server coming online that will be using other test databases on the same server. I don't want the new server to be able to accidentally do anything on the production databases.

I understand I can use REVOKE access, but I'm not sure if that requires altering the existing GRANTS to be more specific to the hosts that they allow. I don't want to guess as the production dbs here are in constant use and accidentally blocking access for the live host would be bad.

Ideally I need to be able to just say:

```
BLOCK ACCESS ON 'xydb'.* TO 'db_user'@'192.168.1.4'
```

Comment: Take a look at this question on Stackoverflow:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621710/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do it using `REVOKE`, but you can definitely do it by inserting an entry into the relevant table in the `mysql` schema:

```
INSERT INTO mysql.db (Host,Db) VALUES ('192.0.2.42','xydb');
INSERT INTO mysql.db (Host,Db) VALUES ('host.example.com','xydb');
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The first two lines do the heavy lifting of inserting into the DB; it's best to put both the IP and hostname in there, for clarity, while still ensuring that even if reverse lookups aren't working, the IP will still be blocked.  The `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` is required because MySQL doesn't look in the tables every time it needs to know something -- it caches the info in memory.  You need to tell MySQL to flush its cache.

Comment: Is it safe to just put stuff directly into that table?

Comment: Yep.  That's all `GRANT`/`REVOKE` do anyway.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks. It'd be handy to know if/when the test server is trying to access the database - I had a quick look in the log but this isn't showing... any ideas where to look?

Comment: Best to ask that as a separate question.  In no small part because, off the top of my head, I don't know.  (grin)

Comment: https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/12/28/auditing-login-attempts-in-mysql/ this is it :)

Answer (score 1):

If the `xydb` could have a different mysql password on the production and test DB servers, then you can [give the mysql user a "wrong" password on the live server](http://mysqlblog.fivefarmers.com/2013/08/30/implementing-a-host-blacklist-with-mysql-privileges/)

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-------------------------+
| VERSION()               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.1.73-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 |
+-------------------------+
```

To recreate your situation:

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR db_user@`localhost`;
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'db_user' on host 'localhost'
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR db_user@`%`;
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'db_user' on host '%'

mysql> CREATE DATABASE xydb;
mysql> GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'db_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '1234';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `xydb`.* TO 'db_user'@'%';
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR db_user@`%`;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for db_user@%                                                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'db_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*A4B6157319038724E3560894F7F932C8886EBFCF' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `xydb`.* TO 'db_user'@'%'                                                      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This results with the user being able to login from localhost

```
$ mysql -u db_user -p1234 --host localhost xydb -e 'SHOW DATABASES'
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| xydb               |
+--------------------+
```

And then a user is added specifically for the host that will be blacklisted.

```
mysql> GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'db_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'AAAAAA';
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR db_user@`localhost`;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for db_user@localhost                                                                                   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'db_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*4F1779C9918AA4ADD1DDB16A274A8D098DDCC0D0' |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and then the user can no longer login (unless of course he gives the proper password)

```
mysql -u db_user -p1234 --host localhost xydb -e 'SHOW DATABASES'
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```